# Mysql:sequlize query returns empty result

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Here is my raw query

```
select * from USER where concat_ws(' ',firstName,lastName) 
like '%ammu sudev%' OR email LIKE "%ammu sudev%"
```

Sequlize query

```
Users.findAll({
    where: {
        $or: [
        Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat_ws', Sequelize.col('firstName'), ' ', Sequelize.col('lastName')), {
            like: '%' + keyword + '%'
        }),
            { email: { $like: '%' + keyword + '%' } },
            { company: { $like: '%' + keyword+ '%' } }
        ]
    }
}).then((result)=>{
    console.log("Query",result);
    callback(result);
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Error",error);
    callback(false);
})
```

But it returns the empty result however the row query returns the proper result

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this line

```
like: '%' + keyword + '%'
```

to

```
$like: '%' + keyword + '%'
```

Within `Sequelize.where` .